# Как окрасить значения из массива в другой цвет?

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = "nВАtва"

function checkRuSymbols() {
  var regexp = /[а-яё]/ig; //[а-яё]
  var myArray = data.match(regexp);
  if (myArray) {
    for (var key in myArray)
      console.log(myArray[key]);
  } else {
    alert("Кириллических символов нет!");
  }
}
checkRuSymbols();
```

Наверное надо обернуть в span, затем ему присвоить класс, а стиль класса задать в css? Как проще всего и правильно?

Comment: _«Наверное надо обернуть в span, затем ему присвоить класс, а стиль класса задать в css?»_ - ага. Правильного способа вроде нет, поэтому обычно оборачивают в элемент. Класс не обязателен, если в контейнере нет других элементов того же типа.  (Некоторые особо упоротые личности добавляют стиль инлайном - не делайте так)

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, мыслите в правильном направлении. Например, как-то так:

```js
var data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;

function checkRuSymbols() {
  var regexp = /([а-яё])/ig; //[а-яё]
  var newdata = data.replace(regexp, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = newdata;
}
checkRuSymbols();
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="data">nВАtва</div>
```